# How to calculate the probability of predicting certain football match results

Tags: probability

Could I please ask for help with the following:

The results of eleven football matches (as win, lose or draw) are to be forecast. Out of all the possible forecasts, find how many will have eight correct and three incorrect results.

Not really sure how to attempt this one. The given answer is 1320.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pick the $8$ correct choices, then pick either of the two incorrect options for the other $3$ games.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I normally always would, but in this case I was stumped. lulu's answer got me thinking though. So I could pick the 8 correct results in 11C8 ways = 156 ways. That would leave three results to be picked "wrongly". Well, the number of ways of placing these wrong results in these three places would be 8 (because, let's say the wrong results are represented by 0 and 1, then there are eight ways of arranging: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111) So final answer = 156 * 8 = 1320.

Comment: Yea, that's fine, though the assumption of equiprobable results the questioner asks us to assume is highly unrealistic !

Comment: @trueblueanil No, the question is not a probability question.  The problem is not asking for the number of equally likely outcomes.  Instead, the problem is asking for the number of distinct combinations.  So, it is irrelevant that (for example) having each of the games end in a draw is highly unlikely.

Comment: @user2661923: The header talks of probability.

Comment: @trueblueanil Good point.  So, the OP (i.e. original poster) slightly went off the rails in titling the problem, but the problem composer (presumably) did not supply the title to the problem.

Comment: Yes, quite right. The issue was created by me (the O.P.) in choosing a misleading title for this problem. Apologies.